# Animating SVG elements by CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I [read](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-svg) that SVG animatable properties like `transform` can be animated by CSS transitions. I can animate such things as opacity, but not `transform` - how's it done ?

Comment: Is this proposal is still in the future? http://dev.w3.org/SVG/proposals/css-animation/animation-proposal.html#def_attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opacity is a [CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html), transform is an [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html). CSS properties can be animated by CSS transitions, attributes cannot be animated in that way but can be animated by [SVG SMIL](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html).

Comment: If you use css transform instead of svg attribute transform, you can animate with basically the same effect.